# Get MP3 from Google Translate special letters

Tags: c#, download, mp3, translate, letter

I am using this code:

```
using System.Net;
function() {
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
        {
            Client.DownloadFile("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello", "a.mp3");
        }
}
```

Its working fine. Notice please the English language I am downloading. The main problem comes when I'd like to do the same with language using non-latin letter, for example Thai:

```
using System.Net;
function() {
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
        {
            Client.DownloadFile("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=th&q=สวัสดี", "a.mp3");
        }
}
```

But this is giving me such a nonsence mp3 without that word sound. How to fix it please?

Notice the main structure of this website:

`...translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=**en**&q=**hello**"`

`...translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=**th**&q=**สวัสดี**"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("สวัสดี")` to encode the Unicode characters.